# What is meant by eye in “eye to the side” or “eye to the sky”?

Tags: meaning

The context relates to coils of flexible pipes.

> Coils can be loaded eye to the sky,  eye  to  the  door  or  eye  to  the  side.  Usually  loading  coils  eye  to  the  sky  is  not  so  problematic, as the coil weight is not so high and the weight is better distributed. 
>   Loading eye  to  the  side is  the  common  method  and  usually  used  for  the  heavy  coils.
>
> A
>   ll  guidelines  like  weight  distribution, bedding, 
>   blocking  and  lashing
>   have  to  be  followed
>   by
>   all 
>   stuffing 
>   methods
>   (eye to sky and eye to door)
>
> Also, Coils of pipe may be positioned in an “eye to the side” or “eye to the sky” orientation. When the flexible pipe is coiled and is disposed with its interior channel facing upwards, such that the coil is in a horizontal orientation, then the coils of pipe are referred to as being in an “eye to the sky” orientation. If, instead, the flexible pipe is coiled and disposed such that the interior channel is not facing upwards, such that the coil is in an upright or vertical orientation, then the coils of pipe are referred to as being in an “eye to the side” orientation

Comment: I would assume that "eye" refers to the opening in the center of the coil.

Comment: You might find [***Flatbed Terminology***](https://www.thetruckersreport.com/truckingindustryforum/threads/flatbed-terminology.205765/) useful. Apparently when a large coil is being transported on a truck, if the "eye" of the coil (either of the "open" ends) faces fowards or sideways (as opposed to ***upwards***, "to the sky"), it's called a ***suicide coil*** (truck driver is more likely to end up getting killed if there's an accident and the coil breaks free of its strapping). Fascinating stuff, but a bit domain-specific for ELU.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments.

[HERE](http://www.steveemkentrucking.com/en/securement/) we find diagrams

Eye to the Side
[image: side]

Eye to the Sky
[image: sky]

Comment: Did you find one for pie-eyed?